# Last Reducer is running from last 24 hour for 200 gb of data set

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bulk-load

Hi i have one mapreduce apllication that bulk loads data into HBase .
I have total 142 text files of total size 200gb.
My mapper gets completed within 5 minutes and all reducer also but last one is stuck at 100%.
Its taking very long time and running from past 24 hr .
I have one column family .
My row key is like below .

48433197315|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|4 48433197315|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|38 48433197315|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|41 48433197315|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|23 48433197315|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|7 48433336118|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|17 48433197319|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|64 48433197319|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|58 48433197319|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|61 48433197319|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|73 48433197319|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|97 48433336119|1972-03-31T00:00:00Z|7

I have created my table like this .

```
  private static Configuration getHbaseConfiguration() {
    try {
        if (hbaseConf == null) {
        System.out.println(
            "UserId= " + USERID + " \t keytab file =" + KEYTAB_FILE + " \t conf =" + KRB5_CONF_FILE);
        HBaseConfiguration.create();
        hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "root.fricadev");
        hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx6553m");
        hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "8192");
        hbaseConf.setInt(MAX_FILES_PER_REGION_PER_FAMILY, 1024);
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", KRB5_CONF_FILE);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(USERID, KEYTAB_FILE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hbaseConf;
    }

    /**
     * HBase bulk import example Data preparation MapReduce job driver
     * 
     * args[0]: HDFS input path args[1]: HDFS output path
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (hbaseConf == null)
        hbaseConf = getHbaseConfiguration();
    String outputPath = args[2];
    hbaseConf.set("data.seperator", DATA_SEPERATOR);
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.table.name", args[0]);
    hbaseConf.setInt(MAX_FILES_PER_REGION_PER_FAMILY, 1024);

    Job job = new Job(hbaseConf);
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseBulkLoadDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Bulk Loading HBase Table::" + args[0]);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(HBaseBulkLoadMapperUnzipped.class);

    // job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.acl-view-job",
    // "bigdata-app-fricadev-sdw-u6034690");
    if (HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FUNDAMENTAL_ANALYTIC.equals(args[0])) {
        HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes(args[0]));
        descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(COLUMN_FAMILY));
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(hbaseConf);
        byte[] startKey = new byte[16];
        Arrays.fill(startKey, (byte) 0);
        byte[] endKey = new byte[16];
        Arrays.fill(endKey, (byte) 255);
        admin.createTable(descriptor, startKey, endKey, REGIONS_COUNT);
        admin.close();
        // HColumnDescriptor hcd = new
        // HColumnDescriptor(COLUMN_FAMILY).setMaxVersions(1);
        // createPreSplitLoadTestTable(hbaseConf, descriptor, hcd);
    }

    job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("mapreduce.compress.map.output", true);
    job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("mapreduce.map.output.compress", true);
    job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", true);

    job.getConfiguration().setClass("mapreduce.map.output.compression.codec",
        org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.class, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec.class);
    job.getConfiguration().set("hfile.compression", Compression.Algorithm.LZO.getName());

    // Connection connection =
    // ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf);
    // Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(args[0]));
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, args[1]);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, new HTable(hbaseConf, args[0]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -1);

    System.out.println("job is successfull..........");

    // LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(hbaseConf);

    // loader.doBulkLoad(new Path(outputPath), (HTable) table);

    HBaseBulkLoad.doBulkLoad(outputPath, args[0]);

    }

    /**
     * Enum of counters.
     * It used for collect statistics
     */
    public static enum Counters {
        /**
         * Counts data format errors.
         */
        WRONG_DATA_FORMAT_COUNTER
}
}
```

There is no reducer in my code only mapper .
My ,mapper code is like this .

```
public class FundamentalAnalyticLoader implements TableLoader {

    private ImmutableBytesWritable hbaseTableName;
    private Text value;
    private Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>.Context context;
    private String strFileLocationAndDate;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public FundamentalAnalyticLoader(ImmutableBytesWritable hbaseTableName, Text value, Context context,
        String strFileLocationAndDate) {

    //System.out.println("Constructing Fundalmental Analytic Load");

    this.hbaseTableName = hbaseTableName;
    this.value = value;
    this.context = context;
    this.strFileLocationAndDate = strFileLocationAndDate;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void load() {
    if (!HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FF_ACTION.contains(value.toString())) {

        String[] values = value.toString().split(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.DATA_SEPERATOR);
        String[] strArrFileLocationAndDate = strFileLocationAndDate
            .split(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FIELD_SEPERATOR);

        if (17 == values.length) {
        String strKey = values[5].trim() + "|" + values[0].trim() + "|" + values[3].trim() + "|"
            + values[4].trim() + "|" + values[14].trim() + "|" + strArrFileLocationAndDate[0].trim() + "|"
            + strArrFileLocationAndDate[2].trim();

        //String strRowKey=StringUtils.leftPad(Integer.toString(Math.abs(strKey.hashCode() % 470)), 3, "0") + "|" + strKey;
        byte[] hashedRowKey = HbaseBulkImportUtil.getHash(strKey);
        Put put = new Put((hashedRowKey));


        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FUNDAMENTAL_SERIES_ID),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[0].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FUNDAMENTAL_SERIES_ID_OBJECT_TYPE_ID),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[1].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FUNDAMENTAL_SERIES_ID_OBJECT_TYPE),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[2]));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FINANCIAL_PERIOD_END_DATE),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[3].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FINANCIAL_PERIOD_TYPE),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[4].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.LINE_ITEM_ID), Bytes.toBytes(values[5].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_ITEM_INSTANCE_KEY),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[6].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_VALUE), Bytes.toBytes(values[7].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_CONCEPT_CODE),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[8].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_VALUE_CURRENCY_ID),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[9].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_IS_ESTIMATED),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[10].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_AUDITABILITY_EQUATION),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[11].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FINANCIAL_PERIOD_TYPE_ID),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[12].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_CONCEPT_ID),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[13].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.ANALYTIC_LINE_ITEM_IS_YEAR_TO_DATE),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[14].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.IS_ANNUAL), Bytes.toBytes(values[15].trim()));

        // put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
        // Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.TAXONOMY_ID),
        // Bytes.toBytes(values[16].trim()));
        //
        // put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
        // Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.INSTRUMENT_ID),
        // Bytes.toBytes(values[17].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FF_ACTION),
            Bytes.toBytes(values[16].substring(0, values[16].length() - 3)));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FILE_PARTITION),
            Bytes.toBytes(strArrFileLocationAndDate[0].trim()));

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY),
            Bytes.toBytes(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FILE_PARTITION_DATE),
            Bytes.toBytes(strArrFileLocationAndDate[2].trim()));

        try {
            context.write(hbaseTableName, put);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            context.getCounter(Counters.WRONG_DATA_FORMAT_COUNTER).increment(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        } else {

        System.out.println("Values length is less 15 and value is " + value.toString());
        }

    }
    }
```

Any help to improve the speed is highly appreciated .
[image][image][image]Counter image 
here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that all records go into single region. 
When you created empty table, HBase splitted key address space in even ranges. But because all actual keys share the same prefix, they all go into single region. That means that single region/reduce task does all the job and all others regions/reduce tasks do not do anything useful. You may check this hypothesis by looking at Hadoop counters: how many bytes slow reduce task read/wrote compared to other reduce tasks.

If this is the problem, then you need to manually prepare split keys and create table by using [`createTable(HTableDescriptor desc, byte[][] splitKeys`](http://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#createTable-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor-byte:A:A-). Split keys should evenly divide your actual dataset for optimal performance.

Example #1. If your keys were ordinary English words, then it would be easy to split table into 26 regions by first character (split keys are 'a', 'b', ..., 'z'). Or to split it into 26*26 regions by first two characters: ('aa', 'ab', ..., 'zz'). Regions would not be necessarily even, but this would be anyway better than to have only single region.

Example #2. If your keys were 4-byte hashes, then it would be easy to split table into 256 regions by first byte (0x00, 0x01, ..., 0xff) or into 2^16 regions by first two bytes.

In your particular case, I see two options:

1. Search for smallest key (in sorted order) and for largest key in your dataset. And use them as `startKey` and `endKey` to `Admin.createTable()`. This will work well only if keys are uniformly distributed between `startKey` and `endKey`.
2. Prefix your keys with hash(key) and use method in Example #2. This should work well, but you won't be able to make semantical queries like (KEY >= ${first} and KEY <= ${last}).

Comment: I am not able to decide how to provide splitKeys in the createTable ().Can you please give one example ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort .I just changed as you have explained line by line .But still same thing is happening .I just killed my after 3 hour .My code is working smaller dataset .I have tried with 16 gb of datset .I am gona try with 50 gb next .But with full dataset it same thing .

Comment: What do the Hadoop counters say? Are they evenly loaded?

Comment: I have added counter of my currently running job .

Comment: I still see that all records are going through single reduce task into single region ("Reduce input groups: 1" from second image). How exactly did you modify code?

Comment: Yes .I can see in my job overview that there are 100 reducer but all data is going through one reducer .I just have posted my driver code also as you have suggested i created table like this admin.createTable(descriptor, startKey, endKey, REGIONS_COUNT); If you dont mind can you please look at my driver code if anything i am doing wrong .Also i have md5 hashing in my mapper class

Comment: !!! First argument in `context.write(hbaseTableName, put);` must be row key and not table name. It is clear now why they all go into single reducer.

Comment: Oh Yes ..Thank for pouting out .I have using this for all my bulk load and struggling since then.I am gona run again and will confirm you .Most probaly it should work .Big thanks .I mark answer just after one run .Thanks again

Comment: Hi just one more question when i run job now i get this error Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wrong number of partitions in keyset

Comment: Such error is thrown if number of reduce tasks is not equal to number of regions (when job starts). `configureIncrementalLoad()` calls `setNumReduceTasks()` automatically to match number of regions. Are you sure that you do not override number of reduce tasks manually?

Comment: Yes i am not overriding number of reduce task .

Answer (score 0):

Mostly if a job is hanging at the last minute or sec, then the issue could be a particular node or resources having concurrency issues etc.

Small check list could be:
1. Try again with smaller data set. This will rule out basic functioning of the code.
2. Since most of the job is done, the mapper and reducer might be good. You can try the job running with same volume few times. The logs can help you identify if the same node is having issues for repeated runs. 
3. Verify if the output is getting generated as expected.
4. You can also reduce the number of columns you are trying to add to HBase. This will relieve the load with same volume.

Jobs getting hanged can be caused due to variety of issues. But trouble shooting mostly consists of above steps - verifying the cause if its data related, resource related, a specific node related, memory related etc.

Comment: My Code is working with smaller datset .I resumed the job many times but still progressing with very slow rate 1% in one hour .I left is running for 26 hr but data not inserted into HBase .Not sure what to do .